Creating a grid using javascript without display:grid
i'm currently working on an etch-a-sketch on the odin project. Here's the code I've come up with.
const container = document.querySelector(".container");
const input = document.querySelector("input");
const submitBtn = document.querySelector("button");

function createGrid() {
    let value=input.value;
    for (let i = 0; i < value; i++) {

        
        const createDivRow = document.createElement("div");
        createDivRow.classList.add("gridrow")
         createDivRow.textContent = i;
        container.appendChild(createDivRow);
    }
    
}

function createGridItems() {
    let value = input.value;
    for (let i = 0; i < value; i++) {
        const divRow = document.querySelectorAll(".gridrow");
        const createDivItem = document.createElement("div");
        createDivItem.textContent = "aa";
        divRow.appendChild(createDivItem);
    }
}

submitBtn.addEventListener("click", createGrid);
submitBtn.addEventListener("click", createGridItems);

In the createGrid() function, I aim to create n number of divs(n being the user input from an input textbox), which I have succeeded. The result was n number of divs with class="gridrow" in the con†ainer.
In the createGridItems() function, I'd like to put the same number of divs "n" into each .gridrow row(which I've given the variable divRow).
I tried declaring const divRow = document.querySelector(".gridRow") and the result was n number of divs in the FIRST .gridrow div, which is almost what I wanted.
So, I figured I'd declare const divRow = document.querySelectorAll(".gridrow") to target all the .gridrow I've created and put n number of divs into EACH .gridrow div. As a result, all I got was just empty n number of .gridrow divs, without the divs that I want.
Can anyone tell me where I've gone wrong ? I was sure the code above would work because I've already targeted all the .divrow divs when I declare divRow = document.querySelectorAll(".gridrow").
Thank you!

document.querySelectorAll returns a NodeList (a collection of elements). Did you check the javascript console? your code throws an error when trying to .appendChild over the collection.

document.querySelectorAll returns a NodeList (a collection of elements).
If you checked the javascript console, your code throws an error when trying to .appendChild over the collection.
You instead needed to iterate over that collection and for each item (being a .gridrow) append there a number of elements.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList

Note: Although NodeList is not an Array, it is possible to iterate
over it with forEach(). It can also be converted to a real Array using
Array.from().

This is a quick demo:


const container = document.querySelector(".container");
const input = document.querySelector("input");
const submitBtn = document.querySelector("button");

function createGrid() {
    const value = input.value;
    for (let i = 0; i < value; i++) {        
        const createDivRow = document.createElement("div");
        createDivRow.classList.add("gridrow")
         createDivRow.textContent = i;
        container.appendChild(createDivRow);
    }
    
}

function createGridItems() {  
    const value = input.value;
    //here you select the rows as .gridrow elements
    const divRows = document.querySelectorAll(".gridrow");    
    //iterate over each one of them
    divRows.forEach(divRow =>{
        //and append to it a new div for as many times as the value fetched from the input element
        for(let i=0;i < value; i++){
          const createDivItem = document.createElement("div");
          createDivItem.textContent = "aa";
          divRow.appendChild(createDivItem);
        }        
    });       
}

submitBtn.addEventListener("click", createGrid);
submitBtn.addEventListener("click", createGridItems);
.gridrow{
  border: solid 1px;  
  margin-top: 1em;
}

.gridrow > div {
  border: solid 1px red;
  margin-left: 1em;
  display: inline-block;
}
<div class="container"></div>

<input type="text">
<button>submit</button>



And finally since the performance became a concern among the comments, here is a performance test to show the difference in time for each solution:

addDivsOneByOne took 2.5999999046325684 milliseconds
addDivsInBatch took 2 milliseconds
addDivsUsingInnerHTML took 1 milliseconds



const numElements = 1000;

function addDivsOneByOne(containerId) {
  const container = document.getElementById(containerId);
  for (let i = 0; i < numElements; i++) {
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    div.textContent = `${i + 1}`;
    container.appendChild(div);
  }
}

function addDivsInBatch(containerId) {
  const container = document.getElementById(containerId);
  const fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
  for (let i = 0; i < numElements; i++) {
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    div.textContent = `${i + 1}`;
    fragment.appendChild(div);
  }
  container.appendChild(fragment);
}

function addDivsUsingInnerHTML(containerId) {
  const container = document.getElementById(containerId);
  let html = '';
  for (let i = 0; i < numElements; i++) {
    html += `<div>${i + 1}</div>`;
  }
  container.innerHTML = html;
}

function runBenchmark() {
  document.getElementById('container1').innerHTML = '';
  document.getElementById('container2').innerHTML = '';
  document.getElementById('container3').innerHTML = '';

  const results = [];

  // Measure addDivsOneByOne
  let start = performance.now();
  addDivsOneByOne('container1');
  let end = performance.now();
  results.push(`addDivsOneByOne took ${end - start} milliseconds.`);

  // Measure addDivsInBatch
  start = performance.now();
  addDivsInBatch('container2');
  end = performance.now();
  results.push(`addDivsInBatch took ${end - start} milliseconds.`);

  // Measure addDivsUsingInnerHTML
  start = performance.now();
  addDivsUsingInnerHTML('container3');
  end = performance.now();
  results.push(`addDivsUsingInnerHTML took ${end - start} milliseconds.`);

  // Display results
  document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = results.join('<br>');
}
.container {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.container div {
  margin: 2px 0;
}
<div id="results"></div>

<div class="container" id="container1"></div>
<div class="container" id="container2"></div>
<div class="container" id="container3"></div>
<div>
  <button onclick="runBenchmark()">Run Benchmark</button>
</div>




Hi, thank you so much, this worked! Just so I'm clear, when I run divRows with forEach(), it treats divRows as an array instead of a nodeList ? Is that why it worked ?

just one thing to add here, you are appending the child on each iteration, which might affect the performance depending on the number of elements, instead, make a temporary variable that collects all elements, then append it one time.

@AndreyWidjaja I edited the answer adding a reference to the NodeList mdn page.. stating literally the despite not being an array it's still iterable. And by the way there's no performance issues in appending children like that in the loop. It would require a benchmark to see the difference in adding them all at once instead of doing it one by one but it really sounds cutting the hair in half when the magnitude is in the order of hundreds

@DiegoD ah i see i'll read up on that mdn page! still abit foggy about the concept..

@MHDAlaaAlhaj I'm not quite sure how to do this yet, Where I am on the odin project has just finished practicing for loops so thats what I used. Thanks for the input anyways!

@DiegoD I haven't said that NodeList isn't iterable I even mentioned the same link in my answer that you already commented on. my comment was about the performance. You have to know that whenever there is a chance to enhance the performance, even if that chance is as tiny as 1%, we have to go for that, especially when there is no huge change will be made to achieve it. If you really don't know about the performance effect of that, I encourage you to read more about Repaint and Reflow

Repaint - Reflow and here is a good starting point to learn more about them

yes you are right and I was aware there are difference in performance... but to be honest I was sure that engaging the html parser when using innerHTML was going to slow down the process... I was wrong. Anyway I added a benchmark that will show, given an arbitrary amount of divs to add (1000 default), will show the time needed for each of those 3 different approaches

@DiegoD That's a great effort you've made here, thanks for the explanation!

That's because querySelectorAll() returns a static (not live) NodeList:
As per MDN:

The Document method querySelectorAll() returns a static (not live)
NodeList representing a list of the document's elements that match the
specified group of selectors.

While NodeList is not equal to array, it's called array-alike but when it's static, any changes in the DOM will not affect the content of the nodes collection.
As per MDN:

Static NodeLists
In other cases, the NodeList is static, where any changes in the DOM do not affect the content of the collection.
The ubiquitous document.querySelectorAll() method returns a static
NodeList.

That said, you have to convert the NodeList to an array first, then do your changes, and finally, inject your html and the simplest way to convert it to an array is by using the spread operator, like so:
function createGridItems() {
  let value = input.value;
  for (let i = 0; i < value; i++) {
    // wrap with brackets, then use spread
    const divRow = [...document.querySelectorAll(".gridrow")];
    const createDivItem = document.createElement("div");
    createDivItem.textContent = "aa";
    // use push instead of appendChild
    divRow.push(createDivItem);
    // now loop throgh divrow
    let html="";
    divRow.forEach(el=> html+=el.outerHTML);
    document.querySelector("WHATEVER_SELECTOR_YOU_WANT").innerHTML = html
  }
}


you are still calling appendChild over an array

I posted my own answer because you didn't get the point.. now you are just pushing elements into an array not being related with the dom.. what's its aim??

hi, I tried running your reply but it still doesn't work. I tried googling how to turn a nodelist into an array and I found the Array.from() method.

i tried turning divRow to array with const arrayDivRow = Array.from(divRow) and then i tried to append arrayDivRow with createDivItem, but it still didn't work. any idea where it went wrong ?

thanks to @DiegoD pointed out that yes I created the array but then I did not inject it into the html, I edited my answer to fix that.
